# ScrollPane JavaFX make it scroll more?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

In javaFX scrollpane. It scrolls so slowly.. Any method to boost it up? I've looked all over here, and no luck.. I've found some thread about listview..

**Demonstration:**

[image]

Comment: I see that there is a method on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#setUnitIncrement for setting the unit Increment. But how can i access it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in the FXML styling.

```
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar:vertical {
-fx-unit-increment: 5 ;
-fx-block-increment: 5 ;
}

.scroll-pane .scroll-bar:horizontal {
-fx-unit-increment: 5 ;
-fx-block-increment: 5 ;
}
```

Play around with the unit and block increment numbers until you get a desired effect.

Comment: Seems like you got something. But I'm not committed to this project anymore. I'll accept this answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set cache to true.

In the pane inside the scrollpane not scrollPane.

yourPane.setCache(true);

Or in SceneBuilder
Properties-Extras-select Cache CheckBox

Comment: I'm no longer committed to the project anymore. How does cache control the amount you're able to scroll?